# Lazy Services via Plugin Manager

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to use [Lazy Services](https://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3.1/modules/zend.service-manager.lazy-services.html#lazy-services) in ZF2 via a custom *plugin manager* (rather than the service manager).

The plugin manager looks like this.

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\RuntimeException;

class EntityServiceManager extends AbstractPluginManager
{
    protected $autoAddInvokableClass = false;

    public function validatePlugin($service)
    {
        if ($service instanceof EntityServiceInterface) {
            return;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
            'Services created by \'%s\' must be of type \'%s\'; \'%s\' provided in \'%s\'.',
            get_called_class(),
            'EntityServiceInterface',
            (is_object($service) ? get_class($service) : gettype($service)),
            __METHOD__
        ));
    }
}
```

As per the documentation; I have configured the service 'UserService' to be lazy loaded via this plugin manager.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Proxy\\LazyServiceFactory'
            => 'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Proxy\\LazyServiceFactoryFactory',
    ],
],
'lazy_services' => [
    'class_map' => [
        'User\\Entity\\User' => 'User\\Service\\UserService',
    ],
],
'entity_service_manager' => [
    'delegators' => [
        'User\\Entity\\User' => [
            'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Proxy\\LazyServiceFactory',
        ],
    ],
    'factories' => [
        'User\\Entity\\User' => 'User\\Factory\\Service\\UserServiceFactory'
    ],
],
```

The issue is that the `LazyServiceFactory` is registered with the ServiceManager and therefore cannot be found when the service is requested via `$entityServiceManager->get('Spectrum\\User\\Entity\\User')`.

The error is:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\ServiceManager\Proxy\LazyServiceFactory::__construct() must be an instance of ProxyManager\Factory\LazyLoadingValueHolderFactory, none given

This is because the plugin manager will create the factory as an invokable and not via the registered `LazyServiceFactoryFactory`.

I have tried providing a peering manager to the plugin manager to allow it to find the factory via the 'parent' service manager.

```
`$entityServiceManager->addPeeringServiceManager($serviceManager);`
```

This allows the factory to be found, however it fails to validate in the `validatePlugin()` method.

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Services created by 'EntityServiceManager' must be of type 'EntityServiceInterface'; 'Zend\ServiceManager\Proxy\LazyServiceFactory' provided in 'EntityServiceManager::validatePlugin'.'

How can I register a lazy service with a plugin manager?

Comment: @Ocramius ? :-p

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll have to register the `LazyServiceFactory` manually in your plugin manager and provide a custom factory for it that does fetch it from your plugin manager's parent service locator:

```
'entity_service_manager' => [
    'delegators' => [
        'User\\Entity\\User' => [
            'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Proxy\\LazyServiceFactory',
        ],
    ],
    'factories' => [
        'User\\Entity\\User' => 'User\\Factory\\Service\\UserServiceFactory',
        'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Proxy\\LazyServiceFactory' => function ($pluginManager) {
            return $pluginManager->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\\ServiceManager\\Proxy\\LazyServiceFactory');
        }
    ],
],
```

Untested but should give you the idea. The approach with fetching the instance from the parent service locator is required to avoid double-instantiation of the factory (once for the global service manager, once for your plugin manager).

**Updated**
As pointed out in the comments, the plugin manager won't allow creation of the `LazyServiceFactory`. I could think of two approaches to this:

1) There is nothing saying that the `validatePlugin` method may only check  and pass for one plugin. As you implement the `validatePlugin` method yourself, you can allow the `LazyServiceFactory` to be created as well. This might not be the best approach strictly speaking as the plugin manager should stick to one interface returned.

2) Instead of relying on the plugin manager to create the `LazyServiceFactory` through the factory as above, you could inject an instance of the `LazyServiceFactory` upon creation in the `EntityServiceManager`'s factory using the `setService` method:

```
class YourPluginManagerFactory extends AbstractPluginManagerFactory
{
    const PLUGIN_MANAGER_CLASS = 'EntityServiceManager';

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $name, array $options = null)
    {
        $instance = parent::__invoke($container, $name, $options);
        $lazyFactory = $container->get(LazyServiceFactory::class);
        $instance->setService(LazyServiceFactory::class, $lazyFactory);
    }
}
```

This *should* bypass the checks of the `validatePlugin` method.

3) As a last idea, while not in line with dependency injection, your plugin manager receives an instance of the parent service manager as the `constructor`'s first argument. From there you could do the same as with the factory.

Comment: This is really what occurs when I add the [service manager as a peering service locator](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/blob/release-2.5.1/src/ServiceManager.php#L540) (this has been removed after version 2.5.1 which would make your suggestion the better option). The issue now is that the `validatePlugin()` method throws the second exception as the `LazyServiceFactory` is not an instance of `EntityServiceInterface`. I see that all other plugin managers perform a similar check so there must be a way to configure it correctly.